# How to calculate sum?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datatable with checkboxes, and I want to calculate salary per day of a salary we use jQuery, in my console there is a result error for the 1st line and for others it works well.

```
 <div id='form2'>
    <h3>form group 2</h3>
    <h4>DATE : <span id="dateE"></span></h4>
    <h4>chantier : <span id="ch"></span></h4>
    <h4>ouvrage : <span id="ou"></span></h4>
      <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
        <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage</button>
      </div>
   <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <th>Archive</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>matricule</th>
            <th>nom & prenom</th>
            <th>salaire net</th>
            <th>nbre de jour </th>
            <th>prime</th>
        </tr>
        @if($salaries->count())
            @foreach($salaries as $key => $salarie)
                <tr id="tr_{{$salarie->id}}">
                  <td>archive</td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="{{$salarie->id}}"></td>
                  <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $salarie->matricule }}</td>
                  <td >{{ $salarie->nom }} {{ $salarie->prenom }}</td>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="salaire" value="{{ $salarie->salairenet }}">{{ $salarie->salairenet }}</td>
                  <td ><input type="text" class='input2' name="nbreJ" class="form-control" ></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </table>
 </div>
```

jquery code, all the values are displayed exactly except SUM

```
$("tr").each(function(i, r) {
  if (i > 0 && $(r).find("input").first().prop("checked")) {
    let s = parseInt($(r.cells[5]).text());
    let value = $('#nbr').val();
    let prime = $(r.cells[7]).find('input').val();
    let sum = (((s) / 24) * value) + prime;

    items.push({
      s,
      value,
      prime,
      sum
    });

  }
  console.log(items);
});
```

Comment: [Are we back here again?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: Why aren't you calculating the sum server-side in (what I assume is) PHP? You have all the data there already, it seems strange to display it then try to scrape it from the page with jQuery to do more stuff with it.

Comment: What is the error? Note you are adding a number to a string since input values are strings not numbers String + Number = String

Comment: why one gives me good result for the other line

Comment: Look this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7629ucgr/) . Without parseInt it's treat like string and try to Concat  two string not to calculate  number. Remove parseInt from val of input and see the effect on fiddle.

Comment: yh exactly thx  its wotk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt` on val. Without `parseInt` it's treat like string and try to `concat` two string not to calculate number. Remove `parseInt` from val of input and see the effect on snippet.

```js
$( "p" ).click(function() {
let s = 24;//parseInt($(r.cells[5]).text());
let value = parseInt($('#nbr').val());
let prime = parseInt($('#test').val());//5;//$(r.cells[7]).find('input').val();
let sum = (((s)/24) * value ) + prime;
alert(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='nbr'/>
<input type='text' id='test'/>
<p>Click for test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = $(document).find('tr[id^="tr_"]');
var data = [];
 rows.each(function(){
   var row = $(this);
   var checkbox = row.find('[type=checkbox]');
   if(checkbox.is(':checked')){
     var nbr = row.find('#nbreJ').val();
     var prime = row.find('[name=prime]').val();
     var salary = row.find('[name=salaire]').val();
     var sum = salary / 24 * nbr + prime;
     data.push({nbr, prime, salary, sum});

   }

 })
console.log(data);
```